# How to drop packages on The Golden Path Supply mission in Far Cry 4?

Tags: pc, far-cry-4

Here I am hung on The Golden Path Supply mission.

I know how to pick the bags. I know what location to travel to. I can travel to the location. But I can't find where to drop it. There is no man on the land there. There is only a bush. There is no interactivity button appearing, like <kbd>E</kbd>.

What to do? Anybody already passed that mission, can they help me please?

Answer (score 4):

Many of the drop off points are in shallow cave inset into the side of a hill. So there's a very good chance that you're actually standing *above* the drop-off point.

Go downhill and look for a cave entrance. You'll find a metal door where you're supposed to drop the supplies.